# Convert dict to a dataframe with keys repeating for each value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Given a dict:

```
{1: [1,2,3,4,5], 2: [55,22,112]}
```

I want to build a dataframe:

```
key_id ids
1      1
1      2 
1      3
1      4
1      5
2      55
2      22
2      112
```

How can I do this?
I am trying to play with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` but it seems as not the right approach.
Also tried to run over the dict, and create a list with the same key as long as the value list's length.
Is there any efficient way to do this?

P.S sometimes it will be a dataframe as value:

```
{0: pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 3}})}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple list comprehension would suffice here:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(k, i) for k, v in d.items() for i in v], 
    columns=['key_id', 'ids']
)
```

---

```
   key_id  ids
0       1    1
1       1    2
2       1    3
3       1    4
4       1    5
5       2   55
6       2   22
7       2  112
```

Comment: list comps are magic in python :) nice one.

Comment: Hey @Umar.H. totally agree with you ...looks like we both have list comp answers :-)

Comment: This _is_ nice, but mozway's one is admittedly very cool as well :)

Comment: @richardec Agreed :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution I just though of (probably not the best):

```
df = (pd.json_normalize(d).T
        .reset_index()
        .explode(0)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .set_axis(['key_id', 'ids'], axis=1)
     )
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   key_id  ids
0       1    1
1       1    2
2       1    3
3       1    4
4       1    5
5       2   55
6       2   22
7       2  112
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Series and `explode`:

```
d = {1: [1,2,3,4,5], 2: [55,22,112]}
df = (
 pd.Series(d, name='ids')
   .explode()
   .rename_axis('key_ids').reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   key_ids  ids
0        1    1
1        1    2
2        1    3
3        1    4
4        1    5
5        2   55
6        2   22
7        2  112
```

Comment: and if the value is not a list but a dataframe with one column A for example? How can I access the A column content? Is it doable or should I prefer the list comprehension answer by Shubham Sharma?

Comment: @Steve depends on the format of the input and expected output. Can you provide an example?

Comment: {0:    request_id
 0           3}
Is the minimal example of key: df column

Comment: A python object as edit to the question would be more explicit ;)

Comment: as you've requested please find edited question and thank you so much for your answer! You are a true professional!

Comment: @SteveS there's still ambiguity, is the dictionary value a dictionary or a DataFrame? If DataFrame use `df = pd.concat(d)`

Comment: It's a key: DataFrame structure @mozway

Answer (score 2):

another way is to use a list comp & assign.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'ids' : v}
             ).assign(key_ids=k) for k,v in d.items()])[['key_ids', 'ids']]


print(df)

   key_ids  ids
0        1    1
1        1    2
2        1    3
3        1    4
4        1    5
0        2   55
1        2   22
2        2  112
```

---